# How to make sure that after the player’s movement and playing the motion animation, the animation of the rack (Idle)

Tags: game-maker-studio-2

How to make sure that after the player’s movement and playing the motion animation, the animation of the rack (Idle) starts, this should work in both directions (right, left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think alternatively, you can also use `else` instead of an if statement, it makes the code cleaner that way:

```
var right_move = (keyboard_check(ord("D")));
var left_move = (keyboard_check(ord("A")));

if (right_move) {
    phy_position_x += 10;
    sprite_index = Move_right;
    image_speed = 1;
} else {
    sprite_index = Idle_right;
}


if (left_move) {
    phy_position_x -= 10;
    sprite_index = Move_left;
    image_speed = 1;
} else {
    sprite_index = Idle_left;
}
```

If the left sprite is the same as the right sprite, then you can also use `image_xscale` and change the scale to `1` or `-1` to flip the sprite.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it is necessary to use keyboard_check_released

```
var right_move = (keyboard_check(ord("D")));
var left_move = (keyboard_check(ord("A")));
var right_move_release = (keyboard_check_released(ord("D")));
var left_move_release = (keyboard_check_released(ord("A")));


if (right_move) {
    phy_position_x += 10;
    sprite_index = Move_right;
    image_speed = 1;
}

if (right_move_release) {
    sprite_index = Idle_right;
}


if (left_move) {
    phy_position_x -= 10;
    sprite_index = Move_left;
    image_speed = 1;
}

if (left_move_release) {
    sprite_index = Idle_left;
}
```